# Resources debunking false coronavirus claims in languages other than English

Tags: discussion, sources

I recently came across a facebook post claiming that 5G causes COVID-19, and that vaccines against the virus will contain microchips. I found it very hard to find Spanish-language resources debunking the former claim - I eventually found https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-52803270 . I also found some material on the [WHO's web site](https://www.who.int/es/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/advice-for-public/myth-busters), but I don't think people will trust the WHO that much.

Are there any resources providing debunkings of false coronavirus claims in languages other than English?